# How to construct condition in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to construct a condition for my dataframe in a function by iterating through the given dictionary **dict**.

```
def get_condition(dataframe, dict={'col1':val1, 'col2':val2, 'col3':val3})":

     condition = ...          

     return condition
```

**Expected output**

`condition = (dataframe['col1']==val1) & (dataframe['col2']==val2) & (dataframe['col3']==val3)`

How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to build a string, or to actually execute and resolve this condition ?

Comment: At the end I want to have a dataframe_new = dataframe[condition] . But I want construct this condition first iteratively using a function.

Comment: I think stroring the strings and then using eval() would work, if I understood what you want ? But it sounds like a code smell ?

Comment: See answer. In reference to your original code, beware of [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/). Also, by using `dict` as the variable name for your dictionary, you're overwriting the builtin dict type/function, which should generally be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_condition(df, d):
    d = list(d.items())

    first_col, first_val = d[0]
    cond = df[first_col] == first_val
    for col, val in d[1:]:
        cond &= df[col] == val

    return cond
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if you want to create a boolean filter.

```
def get_condition(dataframe, dictionary):
    # create series with all values set to true
    condition = pd.Series([True] * len(dataframe))

    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        condition &= dataframe[k] == v
    return condition
```